# window.open() não carrega a página

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Estou a tentar abrir um link numa nova janela/tab mas quando ela abre não carrega.

**Controller:**

```
public static Result loadCreateArtigo(){
     return ok(request().host()+request().path());
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.SmartMessageBox({
  buttons : '[Não][Sim]'
}, 
function(ButtonPressed) {
  if (ButtonPressed === "Sim") {            
    Controller.loadCreateArtigo().ajax({
      success: function(data){
          window.open(data);
      },                   
  });
});
```

A variável 'data' retorna-me o url. O que acontece é que abre-me uma nova tab com o url direito mas a página não carrega. se der F5 a página carrega direito.
Estou a utilizar o Google Chrome.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Cara, tenta passar o parâmetro `"_blank"` junto -> `window.open(data, "_blank");`

Comment: Já tentei isso mas não funciona. Já descobri a solução. o window.open() tem de receber um url absoluto, por isso, se o host recebido no data não contiver o http[s] é necessário adicioná-lo:  window.open("http://"+data);

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

como mencionado por nosso amigo @hugo-machado, é necessário incluir

```
'http:// ou https://'
```

na URL, em seu caso no data.

para testar, vc pode:

```
//verificar se existe http ou https
var data = 'http://asdasd' 
if(data.search(/https?\:\/\//ig) < 0){
    //caso não tenha, coloca pelo menos um http://
    data = 'http://'+data
    alert(data);
}
```

a busca utiliza regex, conforme explicado [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)

espero ter ajudado